# Google Forms&Sheets message to GCP pub-sub

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-forms, google-cloud-pubsub

I  have this issue, I have a form that collects some data and inserts it into a google sheet, I have set up the scripts for it to send a message to pub-sub every time a new entry is added to the sheet, but I'm having these two errors

Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.

Exception: You do not have permission to call Session.getActiveUser. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

My GCP and sheets environment setup is similar as [This medium post](https://medium.com/@jankrynauw/google-pub-sub-cron-job-using-google-apps-script-ef218626218d) I have set up the correct OAuth calls in the appsscript.json in the Google Apps script, but it still gives those errors on each trigger, Am I missing something in the setup? or is this not the correct way to handle messages between google forms and GCP pub-sub?

Comment: You can't open up a user interface in a formSubmit because the user interface doesn't open up unless there is a user

Comment: Are your scripts also similar to the Medium post? If not, could you share your script (without any sensitive information)?